# Info to display in a list in Android

Tags: java, android

I will try to make this as clear as I can. Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

I am downloading information from an SQL table in a database online to the phone. In the LogCat, I have been able to go through the table and see all the information I want. I am wondering about how best to save the information on the phone. I do not think that is necessary to create a new local database. Should I create a cursor with the information from the online database or store it in some kind of structure?

1. The data does not need to be stored for a long time and when the application is closed it is ok to lose it.
2. I want to be able to see information from one of the columns from the SQL table in a list format and then click on it and see all the information from the row of that item in another activity. I have done this in another part of the app but it is using data from a local database on the phone.

Here is some code to help clarify:

```
Log.d("Provider Tester", "Result printed is: " + result);     

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","Name: "+json_data.getString("Name")+
                        ", DateTime: "+json_data.getString("DateTime")
                );
```

I want to be able to show a list of names and then click on a name and see the corresponding date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with loosing the data, you can keep it in memory as long as it is not too big.

As for the ListActivity, you would use an ArrayAdapter if your data is in memory.

Comment: how do I make it so that when I click on one of the items in the arrayadapter I see the information corresponding to that item? Is it possible so that if I click on "George", I see the date associated with that name?

Comment: That entirely depends on how is your data modeled. You probably will have some kind of data manager that will give you the list of the data so you can display the list of name, and some method to obtain the details for a selected item. Which you have to identify somehow

Comment: I am a bit unsure of how to implement this. I have been trying to search, but can't see how to make what I am after.

Comment: how do I make a list with items with data attached to each item (but not displayed until the item is clicked)

Comment: you need a model. that can be an object that holds the information for an item. then you can have an array of these, that you put in a list view, displaying only part of the information, then you can have another page that displays more of the item information. The first thing you need is a model